# Reactjs client for Swagger / OpenAPI API specification

Tags: reactjs, typescript, swagger, flowtype, swagger-codegen

### Background

Using [Swagger Editor](http://swagger.io/swagger-editor/), I created a spec for my API.
I see that Swagger also provide a "Generate a client" option in their Swagger Editor (probably using [Swagger Codegen](http://swagger.io/swagger-codegen/)).

### Objective

I want to generate a client and use it in my React app (created with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)), and preferably enjoy some static typing capabilities (currently using [flow](https://flow.org/)).

### Currently

None of the options in Swagger Editor there seem to work:

- `javascript` - provides a vanilla node module that you need to `npm install` it as a dependency to your project. Now, not only this doesn't have any classes / types, but also fails with:

  `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "ApiClient"
  at webpackMissingModule (index.js:17)
  at exports.ApiClient (index.js:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:22)
  at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 75f547b…:555)
  at fn (bootstrap 75f547b…:86)
  at new Index (index.js:87)
  at ReactCompositeComponent.js:295
  at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
  at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (ReactCompositeComponent.js:294)
  at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:280)`
- `typescript-*` options are not compatible with js, and I don't necessarilty know how / want to add TypeScript to my project.
- `*-angular` options are of course irrelevant.

### Approaches

- Generate `.ts` file and covert it to `flow`. How??
- Manually adding the generated `.js` files to my project. Currently doesn't work as the generated code comes with its own dependencies.
- Add TypeScript to my project (should I replace `flow` then?). How??

Thanks

Comment: For usage issue with the JS API client, please open an issue via https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/new so that the community can help on that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution until a generator is out to use dynamic implementation such as [swagger-js](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js)